# Save payment method only if valid

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using the Stripe Payment Intent api together with Stripe Elements to handle customers credit card payments.

I want to enable customers to have their payment methods saved for later usage.
This works fine by using

```
await this.stripe.handleCardPayment(
            clientSecret, cardElement, {
                ...
                save_payment_method: true
            })
```

The only problem for me is, that even if a card is rejected for various reasons, it is still attached to the customer.

Is there a way to only save the card if the payment was successful, without making an additional call?

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution? I have the same issue, `handleCardPayment` even duplicates card instead of updating details or ignoring them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find a solution other than saving the card from the serverside once the payment was successful.